# jQuery slicing and click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably a really simple jQuery question, but I couldn't answer it after 10 minutes in the documentation so...

I have a list of checkboxes, and I can get them with the selector `'input[type=checkbox]'`. I want the user to be able to shift-click and select a range of checkboxes. To accomplish this, I need to get the index of a checkbox in the list, so I can pass that index to `.slice(start, end)`. How do I get the index when the user clicks a box?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following selector should also work in jQuery: `input:checkbox`.

You can then string the `:gt(index)` and `:lt(index)` filters together, so if you want the 5th to 7th checkboxes, you'd use `input:checkbox:gt(4):lt(2)`.

To get the index of the currently clicked checkbox, just use `$("input:checkbox").index($(this))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick solution, but I would give each checkbox a unique ID, perhaps with an index hint, like so:

```
<input id="checkbox-0" type="checkbox" />
<input id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" />
<input id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" />
<input id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" />
<input id="checkbox-4" type="checkbox" />
```

You can then easily obtain the index:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    index = /checkbox-(\d+)/.exec(this.id)[1];
    alert(index);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, samjudson.

After further experimentation, I found that you can even use just `$(':checkbox')` to select them. It's interesting that you can use the `.slice()` function to get the range, but you also have the option of doing it in the selector with `:gt` and `:lt`. I do find the syntax of `.slice()` to be cleaner than using the selector filters, though.

I'm going to have to say that I don't like Ryan Duffield's solution as much, because it requires changes to the markup, and involves repeating code.

Answer (score 0):

@Gorgapor: I guess I need to take questions a little less literally sometimes.  :-)  I figured you were locked down to requiring some sort of index.  I think you'll find though that as you use jQuery more, you usually don't need to do that sort of thing.